# Disappearing Repeater

Tags: .net, asp.net, repeater

I have a Repeater generating ImageButtons.

When I click an ImageButton or interact with the GridView elswhere on the page, everything generated in my Repeater disappears.

All of my controls are in an UpdatePanel so I dont beleive this is a PostBack issue.

Comment: Show us the code, preferably the ASPX markup for the Repeater and GridView

Comment: BTW, you are sure you are not accidentally setting Repeater.Visible = false somewhere?  The little mistakes will kill ya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to re-bind your repeater on every single page load. An UpdatePanel still causes a postback, albeit a partial one.

It is often common to run your DataBind code within the click events of any buttons and also in a !IsPostBack on the Page_Load.